# Accordion Menu - jQuery seems to stop working on product page

Tags: commerce, routes, javascript, navigation

for several hours I'm struggling to cope with the Accordion Menu in my webshop (Drupal Commerce).

Here's the story...
In my webshop, beside the default content types (Article and Basic Page), I have my own content type - "Product display" which displays related products.
I have a couple views of "Product displays". Furthermore there are pages "About", "Terms and Conditions" etc.

The Accordion Menu works fine everywhere except the product nodes. The jQuery script seems to not working on the product pages. The accordion functionality and its CSS disappears while the menu structure and items are still displayed.

I tried to look for problems using Firebug console. All I found was "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" in "jquery-1.10.2.js:631"

And here is an illustration of my problem:
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!